# Why can't I modify a python script tool or delete the toolbox it's in?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool

So I started getting this weird error for what I thought was no apparent reason:

```
Executing: saveTile
Start Time: Tue Apr 28 20:19:17 2015
Running script saveTile...
Failed script saveTile...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Image_Processing\Python_Scripts_Automation\Save_Tile_Automation.py", line 236, in <module>
    arcpy.createDashboardReport_ipauto(sReports3, sDatetime)
  File "C:\Image_Processing\Image_Processing_Automation.tbx", line 23, in createDashboardReport
    AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <createDashboardReport_ipauto> not found

Failed to execute (saveTile).
Failed at Tue Apr 28 20:20:29 2015 (Elapsed Time: 1 minutes 12 seconds)
```

The tool had been working and it all of a sudden stopped working. Then I got looking, and it seems I no longer have access to the tool. When I open its properties, I can't change the path of the script. I also can't modify the parameters. And the delete option is grayed out when I right click on the toolbox:

[image]

Is there a lock on it somewhere? Has anyone seen this before, or know how to fix it?

Comment: Close out of all your Esri sessions and try delete in explorer (check task manager to ensure that there's not some half closed Catalog that wont go away). Something has gone bad somewhere, which happens from time to time in toolboxes. This (and many other reasons) is why we keep backups. The script should be fine but the toolbox itself is kaput! Is it stored on a network location? Editing toolboxes and models isn't very tolerant of network hiccups... best to edit locally and then copy to a server location if that's where it needs to be (defacto backup)

Comment: @GISUser9. In your case, can you confirm if this is happening? In your script tool, does it import a toolbox (from arcpy), run a tool from that toolbox, and then fails on the next call to a tool from that toolbox??